# ASP.Net MVC3: how to send different values for same field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, query-string, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I send to action of controller different values for same field? Which input parameters should I define in action? And how can I show url with different values of identical fields in querystring? I want to get such url: `site.com/directory?metro=2&metro=3`
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how this would be done in the case of checkboxes.  Note that you wouldn't see the same querystring parameter repeated in the case of a GET request.  Instead you would see "?metros=1,3" if checkboxes 1 and 3 were checked.

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://site.com/directory" method="get">
    <input type='checkbox' name='metros' value='1' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='metros' value='2' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='metros' value='3' />
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public class DirectoryController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<int> metros) {
        foreach (var metro in metros) {
            // do something
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed last line of your action method to: `return View(metros)`. So, I get desirable url site.com?metros=2&metros=3. It works fine!!! Thank you very much!